Apostrophe entered in the title tag as &#039; does not render on mobile version of any browser
I hope that this community can help me with the following query. The title of a website I look after has an apostrophe and this doesn't render on any browser in the MOBILE version ONLY. It actually renders well on the Desktop version. The title tag is as follows:
<title>WebsiteName&#039;</title>

When I analyse the above HTML code in the URL Inspection section of Google search console, I can see that &#039; is highlighted in red. That led me to believe that there is a syntax error in the above title tag. However if that was the case, wouldn't the apostrophe not render on the desktop version either?
Please if anyone could shed some light it would be greatly appreciated.
Kind regards,
Manu S

This snippet as such should be perfectly valid HTML. Please add more context to the question and try to provide a [mre].

Try using a normal apostrophe character instead of a html entity?

Thank you both, I will try to use a normal apostrophe. I have contacted the plug in developer to let them know but they reckon they should use the HTML code instead of the normal apostrophe. So I might disable the plugin and write this manually. Hopefully I will manage to. Thanks a lot

Where do mobile browsers render the title of the a web page?  I wouldn't think they would use the title tag at all.
